# Uncollapse a link back to the default text

Tags: javascript, jquery

This collapse code works fine but I wish to get back the same message when a user does a **un-collapse** by clicking the link.

Code:

```
<div class="expandContent searchfont"><a href="#" title="Click here to search."> &nbsp; &nbsp; <i class='icon-search' title='Click here to search.'></i> SEARCH CANDIDATES</a></div>
<div class="showMe" style="display:none">
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".expandContent").click(function() {
      $(".showMe").slideToggle("slow");
      if ($("#toggleText").text() === "SEARCH") {
        $(".expandContent a").html(` &nbsp; &nbsp;
<i class="icon-search" title="Click here to search."></i><span id="toggleText"> &#45;</span>`);
      } else {
        $(".expandContent a").html(` &nbsp; &nbsp;
<i class="icon-search" title="Click here to search."></i><span id="toggleText"> FILTER SEARCH</span>`);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

All I want is when I use click on Filter Search then the div uncollapse and message should be search candidates.

Comment: better text by fixing mistakes and better title

Answer (score 0):

Everything was fine except

1. `$("#toggleText").text() === "SEARCH"` will be changed by `$("#toggleText").text() === " FILTER SEARCH"`
2. In case the text is `filter search`, the next text will be changed in `search candidate`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".expandContent").click(function() {
      $(".showMe").slideToggle("slow");
      if ($("#toggleText").text() === " FILTER SEARCH") {
        $(".expandContent a").html(` &nbsp; &nbsp;
<i class="icon-search" title="Click here to search."></i>SEARCH CANDIDATES<span id="toggleText"> &#45;</span>`);
      } else {
        $(".expandContent a").html(` &nbsp; &nbsp;
<i class="icon-search" title="Click here to search."></i><span id="toggleText"> FILTER SEARCH</span>`);
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expandContent searchfont"><a href="#" title="Click here to search."> &nbsp; &nbsp; <i class='icon-search' title='Click here to search.'></i> SEARCH CANDIDATES</a></div>
<div class="showMe" style="display:none">Below content</div>
```